# how to get the second param be confined by the first?

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, typescript-generics

Consider the following:

I have an `AbstractTaskProcessor` that looks like the following:

```js
export abstract class AbstractTaskProcessor<T> {

     abstract process(args: T): Promise<void>

}
```

example implementation

```js
interface AccountScoringJobInput {
  accountName: string,
  accountId: string
}

class ScoringTaskProcessor extends AbstractTaskProcessor<AccountScoringJobInput> {
   process(args: AccountScoringJobInput) { // do some work}
}
```

now i want to make a generic processTask function that i would like to call like so:

```js
processTask(ScoringTaskProcessor, {accountName: 'lala', accountId: '123'})
```

what is the typings to do that such that the first argument is an implementation of the `AbstractTaskProcessor`, and the second argument is the args defined by its definition?

Comment: Currently on Version 3.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Try this signature for the `processTask` function:

```
function processTask<T>(process: abstract new () => AbstractTaskProcessor<T>, args: T)
```

Warning: this only works with TypeScript 4.2 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

So @blaumesise -- that was super close and the pointed me the the right direction.

But i struggled with the abstract keyword.  So the following is what did the trick and I think it feels good

added the following utility type:

```
export type Constructable<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T
```

and then it worked really nicely as:

```
function processTask<T>(processor: Constructable<AbstractTaskProcessor<T>>, args: T)
```

getting close to seeing the light with this typescript thing!

Comment: Did it really work? I already had problems with it, and this `abstract new` helped me out.

Comment: yes -- the thing with abstract for me was that my editor was barfing on it (Webstorm) -- but this is working and i think i find it more readable than the inline abstract